# linearizing a power regression

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I am running the following regression:

$y= bX^a + noise$

but instead of using a nonlinear regression, I use a grid approach to find best fit alpha (lowest MSE). I am getting a good fit with independent normal homoskedastic residuals. However, my question is regarding the standard error of alpha. Is there a way to estimate that without resorting to nonlinear approach?

Note: $y$ takes on both positive and negative values so can't linearize by taking logs. I will post a scatter plot shortly.

Comment: Do you mean your model is $y_i = b x_i^a + \epsilon_i$? Do you know anything about the distribution of $\epsilon_i$?

Comment: Is $Y$ always negative or just sometimes? How often Is $X$ negative, zero or positive? Can you list and/or plot the data?

Comment: In my view this isn't clear until we know more about the data. The data might make a power function plausible or implausible and even if it is plausible advice on how to fit it hinges on the precise nature of the data.

Comment: This question is confusing because it clearly *is* a nonlinear regression but asks about something in the "linear setting."  What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: I have edited the question above with some details and will also post the scatter plot shortly to give a better idea about the data.

Comment: Code to do this is presented at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205419. More code and more detailed explanations for very nearly the same model appear at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32824.  More code to compute the model and SEs of coefficients is shown at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151606.  See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6720 for a discussion of versions of this model and how to fit it. A site search produces [a few hundred additional posts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=exp+fit+error) to review.

Comment: Thanks @whuber but I doubt the links you posted relate to my query as they talk about NLS. Will review them in detail soon.

Comment: You performed NLS in a manual, inefficient way--but it was still NLS.

Comment: Agreed, so the question is similar...Would there be a crude and manual (although inefficient) way of finding the approximate variance of alpha.

Comment: Yes--but why would you want to do that, given that good, easily implemented, and clearly described solutions exist?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take logarithm of the right hand side and regress $y=d+a\log(X)$? So redefining the independent variable to be $\log(X)$ and running a standard linear regression.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that y takes on negative values also so can't do that. Edited above.

Comment: Why not? As long as you don't take logarithm of $y$, you should be fine. Or does $X$ also take negative values?

Comment: That is a different model. You need to take $\log$ also of $y$ to keep the model the same.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Can you do some sort of bootstrapping to find out the standard error of $\alpha$?